# How do I outer join and group by in Entity framework Linq?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm having trouble getting my Linq statemnt to work  when doing an outer join and a group by.  Here's a SQL version of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
select p.PRIMARY_KEY, min(p.EFFECTIVE_DATE), sum(IsNull(c.PAID_INDEMNITY, 0))
from PRMPOLCY p 
left outer join CLMMAST c on p.PRIMARY_KEY = c.POLICY_NO 
where p.UNDERWRITER_UID = 93
GROUP BY p.PRIMARY_KEY
```

Here's what I have in Linq (which doesn't work):

```
var result = from p in context.PRMPOLCies
             join c in context.CLMMASTs on p.PRIMARY_KEY equals c.POLICY_NO into polClm
             where (p.UNDERWRITER_UID == underwriter)
from grp in polClm.DefaultIfEmpty()
group grp by p.PRIMARY_KEY into g
         select new PolicySummation()
                                     {
                                         PolicyNo =  g.Key,
                                         Incurred = g.Sum(grp => grp.PAID_INDEMNITY ),
                                         EffDate = g.Min(grp => grp.PRMPOLCY.EFFECTIVE_DATE
                                     };
```

Beating my head against the wall trying to figurwe this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a navigation property set up between `PRMPOLCY` and `CLMMAST`, you shouldn't need to specify the join explicitly.  It's much easier to express most queries in linq without explicit joins, but rather treating your structures as a hierarchy.  I don't know the specifics of your model property names, but I'd take a guess that something like this would work.

```
var result =
    from p in context.PRMPOLCies
    where (p.UNDERWRITER_UID == underwriter)
    select new PolicySummation {
        PolicyNo = p.PRIMARY_KEY,
        Incurred = p.CLMASTs.Select(c => c.PAID_INDEMNITY).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(),
        EffDate = p.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
    };
```

Comment: Thanks recursive, that looks like the right approach. However, the ?? operator is not compiling -  'Left operand of the ?? operator should be of reference or nullable type' The c.PAID_INDEMNITY is not nullable.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JimHoagland: I assumed it was nullable.  You should just be able to remove the `?? 0`.

Comment: Much obliged recursive!

Comment: Recursive, since c.PAID_INDEMNITY is a decimal, shouldn't the .DefaultIfEmpty() function place a zero in the field if no CLMMAST records are tied to the policy?

Comment: @JimHoagland: Hm, not quite.  It would put a null reference of `CLMASTs` in the list, and attempt to sum that.  That's a problem.  I have an idea for a fix, but it's tough for me to test without access to your environment.  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include both your tables in the group clause like this:

```
group new { p, grp } by p.PRIMARY_KEY into g
```

Then in your `Sum` / `Min`

```
g.Sum(grp => grp.grp == null ? 0 : grp.grp.PAID_INDEMNITY )
g.Min(grp => grp.p.PRMPOLCY.EFFECTIVE_DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is still giving me a problem, since in some rows of my result I have a null value for the sum of PAID_INDEMNITY.  How do I do Sum( IsNull(grp => grp.grp.PAID_INDEMNITY, 0)) ?

Comment: @JimHoagland - you can use the ternary operator `? :`